# Error: Unexpected value 'CalendarComponent' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation

Tags: angular

I'm new in angular 2. I want to use 'schedule' of Primeng. So I installed it's package. and added calendarComponent in app.module.ts as shown below:

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CalendarComponent } from 'angular2-fullcalendar/src/calendar/calendar';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CalendarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

```html
//app.component.html
<p-schedule [events]="events"></p-schedule>
```

But when I run the code, I got the error: **Unexpected value 'CalendarComponent' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.**

Comment: Can you post the code for CalendarComponent? The issue will be in that code

Comment: I am using in-built 'calendarComponent' of primeng- @Steverob2k

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the relevant primeng modules to the imports of app.module. So in your case you will need to at the very least import the ScheduleModule from primeng.

```
import {ScheduleModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CalendarComponent } from 'angular2-fullcalendar/src/calendar/calendar';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CalendarComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ScheduleModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

You may need to import other primeng components as part of this aswell depending on what you have used in CalendarComponent.

Also looking at the [primeng documentation for schedule component](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/schedule) you will need to reference full calendar in your index.html page and a few other dependencies:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' />
<script src='lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js'></script>
```

see: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/usage/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is about fullcalendar plugin version. When you install angular2-fullcalendar npm use fullcalendar 3.8.0.

You can fix this issue installing fullcalendar 3.7.0 before angular2-fullcalendar.

```
// package.json
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "3.1.1",
    "@angularclass/conventions-loader": "^1.0.2",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "~1.2.0",
    "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "~3.0.2",
    "fullcalendar": "3.7.0",
    "angular2-fullcalendar": "^1.1.1",
    "angular2-google-maps": "0.16.0",
    "angulartics2": "1.6.2",
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.4.0",
    "classlist": "^1.0.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
    "moment": "2.18.1",
    "ng2-datepicker": "^2.0.0-dev5",
    "ng2-sweetalert2": "^0",
    "raven-js": "^3.19.1",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.6.17"
  },
```

Then run:

```
$ npm install
```

If you wish you can install my fork. It is forked using angular 2.1.1 and fullcalendar 3.7.0:

```
$ npm install iver/ng2-fullcalendar --save
```

https://github.com/iver/ng2-fullcalendar/